# geth mainnet peer connection fails

Tags: go-ethereum

OS: Linux

Geth Version: Version: 1.13.5-stable

I set bootnodes and started geth, but the peer count did not increase.

Adding it using admin.addPeer did not improve it.

When I looked at the log, it was failing due to "RPC timeout".

Although the same enode was specified on other nodes, this phenomenon did not occur.

The settings for the node ports are also the same.

What is wrong?

start command

```
ExecStart=/data/ethereum/bin/geth --datadir /data/ethereum/data \
  --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs \
  --db.engine pebble \
  --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain '*' --http.api engine,admin,eth,net,web3,debug,txpool --http.vhosts '*' \
  --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins '*' --ws.api eth,net,web3,debug,txpool \
  --bootnodes "enode://e152be5f5f0167250592a12a197ab19b215c5295d5eb0bb1133673dc8607530db1bfa5415b2ec5e94113f2fce0c4a60e697d5d703a29609b197b836b020446c7@67.21.92.226:30303,enode://cba43699a9136a78d8da5ee2c63713baf1c0f0a1d08f70a84f28fb00e5127866fe152e4935b2841437546faf78ea8b4e00c65f44a19f39c98e31e4886a0ed7aa@3.1.102.174:30303,enode://34945878fa43ab2dbf3cd23f0cfa9955de902e1c6a28e5a427fd2de22b97fa466cddb50433bbf8c75fef655c732a8538cea71eda32f56cf2aa8d4e8c59cd2529@23.234.9.249:30303,enode://1c9859afa6642c69e92a8ab07a0953784dfc601e48564c8aa9468b5046b4cd0cfebc3a879c3b6754355fd37bc6697e961cfeeb69bb1d31732b9f428d5d76c342@91.121.65.9:30303,enode://b0f1a4c2aa5779cdbe0fc7d207bf1861dd55f8e74953be34530c014e48c3a7d383f9f86f5bf044e6d57577322979a7b366107dd34e24f6a9a9217a5269323fb6@47.74.178.189:30303,enode://46321e6efb5295ac0d7dc7a6e4e2937a02f0136bdc89938e2bc57f41855985724092b80384283af562d4fc2bedbfe6a58246c170617d8d42cdc85107e42916a5@47.105.45.233:30303,enode://5c291037977dcd4c2de59a9f633c0a1ec897bc2ad8d59ae0eb5a09f2fde295ebd92d489438cef1ac3a501dc45c28d48bbd83c6d94de3676af0c32900aeceedac@3.112.194.15:30303,enode://dd93e3cfa1db3e6f7a7019569dc95bb22ed351140461c5c157636dac6a12144b8719f4fb50c4e0e20e3995054701e08f6dd793043a05f1e5f2b69e022b9f93fb@52.78.117.212:30303" \
  --cache 4096 \
  --verbosity 5
```

logs

```
Nov 17 14:50:08 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:08.634] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:08 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:08.635] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:08 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:08.635] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.135] FINDNODE failed                          id=10a67538977606bd failcount=1047 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.135] FINDNODE failed                          id=0c96e0602312ead9 failcount=1327 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.135] FINDNODE failed                          id=9837138f0cd28fe3 failcount=389  dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] Discarding dial candidate                id=10a67538977606bd ip=3.1.102.174   reason="already dialing"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] Discarding dial candidate                id=0c96e0602312ead9 ip=67.21.92.226  reason="recently dialed"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] Discarding dial candidate                id=9837138f0cd28fe3 ip=47.105.45.233 reason="already dialing"
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] >> PING/v4                               id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] >> PING/v4                               id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:09.136] >> PING/v4                               id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:09 geth[8149]: DEBUG[11-17|14:50:09.907] Served eth_blockNumber                   conn=10.12.1.90:58500 reqid=1         duration="28.796µs"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.137] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.138] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.138] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.638] FINDNODE failed                          id=9837138f0cd28fe3 failcount=390  dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] FINDNODE failed                          id=10a67538977606bd failcount=1048 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] FINDNODE failed                          id=0c96e0602312ead9 failcount=1328 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] Discarding dial candidate                id=0c96e0602312ead9 ip=67.21.92.226  reason="recently dialed"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] Discarding dial candidate                id=10a67538977606bd ip=3.1.102.174   reason="already dialing"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] Discarding dial candidate                id=9837138f0cd28fe3 ip=47.105.45.233 reason="already dialing"
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] >> PING/v4                               id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] >> PING/v4                               id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:10 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:10.639] >> PING/v4                               id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:11.124] >> PING/v4                               id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: DEBUG[11-17|14:50:11.624] Removed dead node                        b=15 id=9837138f0cd28fe3 ip=47.105.45.233 checks=0
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:11.641] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:11.641] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=9837138f0cd28fe3 addr=47.105.45.233:30303 err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:11.641] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:11 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:11.646] Dial error                               id=d192ca18a0249323 addr=52.78.117.212:30303 conn=staticdial       err="i/o timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.141] FINDNODE failed                          id=10a67538977606bd failcount=1049 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.141] FINDNODE failed                          id=0c96e0602312ead9 failcount=1329 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.141] FINDNODE failed                          id=9837138f0cd28fe3 failcount=391  dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.141] Discarding dial candidate                id=0c96e0602312ead9 ip=67.21.92.226  reason="recently dialed"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.141] Discarding dial candidate                id=10a67538977606bd ip=3.1.102.174   reason="already dialing"
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.142] >> PING/v4                               id=10a67538977606bd addr=3.1.102.174:30303   err=nil
Nov 17 14:50:12 geth[8149]: TRACE[11-17|14:50:12.142] >> PING/v4                               id=0c96e0602312ead9 addr=67.21.92.226:30303  err=nil
```